# Import pivot table from Excel into SAS EG

Tags: excel, sas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which I need to import into SAS EG. But this pivot table has values coming from database and few values are entered manually.
When I tried to import this pivot table to SAS ., only the values from database got imported. the manual values were not imported into sas. 
Could anyone please help me out, on how to import the manual values from this same pivot table to SAS.

Comment: How are the manual values entered? Are they in a separate location or not in line with the table? You'll need to clarify more information about your problem.

Comment: The manual values are in the same table as the other values. The manual values are calculated values. For example, there is this formula for a particular manual value column  : =IFERROR(OFFSET(TABLES!AY$2, $II2, 0), IF(OR(H2=150, H2=154, F2="GO"), "Group", "Ordinary")) .

Comment: @Reeza : let me know if you want more information. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sharing your SAS log with us would help

Comment: Verify where data is being imported from - the pivot table or data source directly.

Comment: i am trying to import the pivot table to sas, but it doesnt import all the values. the manual values column is blank when i import the pivot table into sas @Reeza .

Comment: @DirkHorsten : i am just trying to import the pivot table using the point and click method

Comment: Never the less, you will have a log.

Comment: @DirkHorsten :  This DATA step reads the data values from DATALINES within the SAS code. The values within the DATALINES were extracted from the Excel  source file by the Import Data wizard.

Comment: @user5678811what data step?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GUI and have added on information to an Excel Pivot table, it likely doesn't belong to the definition of the table as how Excel defines the range. This means SAS will only read what Excel tells it to read, which is the actual pivot table. What you can do is explicitly write a proc import statement and specify the range of your data.  That being said, I wouldn't recommend actually doing this. You have the source data, import that and recreate the pivot table in Excel. It's not a trivial task, but probably useful in the long run.

Here's a sample of a proc import code that should work.

```
proc import datafile='C:\_localdata\myexcel.xlsx' out=want dbms=XLSX replace;
   range='Sheet1$A1:D26'; getnames=YES;
run;
```

Comment: I was trying to do the similar way you mentioned, it still creates dataset in sas with all the values from database but it leave all the manual values empty. Also, my file name is " myexcel.xls " . So when i give DBMS = XLS or XLSX it give me an error saying dbms type is not valid.

Comment: What does not work mean? Please show your log from the code.

Comment: this is the error : 
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /C:\localdiskmyexcel.xls.

Comment: ERROR: DBMS type XLSX not valid for import.

Comment: Are you using EG on a server? You'll need to upload your data to your server. Your application not finding the file is a different issue than truncated  imported data.

Comment: yes, i use EG on Server. i am importing this using server. it gives me Table  with 28853 rows and 237 columns, but i have a table with 31174 rows and 248 columns. So 2321 rows and 11 columns are manual. How can i import them in the same table ?

Comment: Hi, could anyone please help me out on this. I need to import the manually entered values from a pivot table into SAS EG.